# How to generate 3 number combination with repetion

Tags: matlab, random

So basically what I want to generate is a 3 number combination with repetition. So, for example, The range of the number is from 1 to 31, and I have 3 sets. So assume that for the 1st set I randomly pick number 2, then for the 2nd set I randomly pick 12, the for the 3rd set, I randomly pick 31. Then I will have 3 combination 2,12,and 31. And i want to do this with N trials.

I tried to use this code:

```
Y = zeros(3,31);
for i=1:1000
    Y(i,:) = randperm(31);
end
Y = Y(:, 1:3);
```

However, this code is for combination WITHOUT repetition. What I need is combination WITH repetition.

Comment: I think you are looking for `randsample` https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html

Comment: Even tough, in this special case you could even use `randi(31,1000,3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still just choosing numbers uniformly distributed over 1‒31.

```
N = 10;
combinations = randi([1 31], [N 3]);
```

Each row will be 1 of `N` trials.  Each column will be a randomly selected number (w/ replacement) between 1 and 31.